# XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://firestore.googleapis..... due to access control checks

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement firestore in my project.
What I'm doing right now is just implementing it and read some data, but I get the error in the title :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore..... due to access control checks.

I use the following :

```
// Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: "xxx",
            authDomain: "xxx",
            databaseURL: "xxx",
            projectId: "xxx",
            storageBucket: "xxx",
            messagingSenderId: "xxx"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        // Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
        var db = firebase.firestore();

        var docRef = db.collection("users");

        docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                //alert(doc.data().born);
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });
```

The part where I try to retrieve the data cause the error (docRef.get()...)

Do you have an idea why is this error happening ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm running into the same issue...

Comment: Same here, but I just see this error in safari...By the way, I see the error but I'm able to read the data

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need to update your Firestore Security Rules.  You can do this via the "Rules" tab of the Database page in the Firebase Console website.

Docs about Firestore Rules are here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

You can use this ruleset to make it accessible to anyone.  I would use these rules just to make sure that you were able to fix your problem.  After that, I would tweak your rules so they match the amount of security (or sensitivity) your app's data needs.

`service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}`

Comment: I have tried this and waited for about 15 minutes, and i still can't get it to work. Do you know why?

Comment: With this change of rules from a timestamp less than, the warning was vanquished!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else with this same issue, it has been reported and the resolution is still in progress: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3708

Edit:
Even though the thread in the link above wasn't resolved, it was closed. The issue still occurs for me.

Comment: Please add a summary of the answer  and not just a link as it could go 404 in the futur

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Understood, but like I said the issue isn't resolved yet so I'll update my answer when that happens. I just wanted to inform others with this problem that Firebase developers are looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

.json is missing at the end of your post request

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please check the URL given, it is not dealing with rtdb, so we don't need  ".json" at the end.