# Firebase Cloud Functions + Hosting - 404 Not Found

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, incognito-mode

I'm building my web app on top of Firebase cloud functions, and hosting. My client was built with create-react-app, and I have a small express server running in a cloud function that serves the app build.

Everything works fine in a normal browser window however, I am having an issue where if I go to any url that is not '/' in incognito mode or a mobile device I get a 404 and "Not Found"

ie: hitting "https://144blocks.com/week" directly will load fine in a normal browser window but throws the following error in incognito and mobile.

[image]

My firebase function for serving the site is:

**functions/index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    const fullPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../react-ui/build/index.html');

    res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
    res.sendFile(fullPath);
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

In my client my firebase.json file:

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "react-ui/build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why I can't hit any route directly aside from '/' in an incognito window or a mobile device. Ideally, I want all my routes to flow through the one `app.get(/*` on my express server and have my client handle the routing.

Comment: fyi: [that URL](https://144blocks.com/week) gives a 404 for me in Chrome on a Mac too. The app looks great btw, at least in the homepage animation. :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for double checking and the compliments on the app 

Comment: @Onaracs how did you end up fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a problem with Firebase Hosting, which appears to be affecting a number of sites, including two of my own. You can stay up-to-date with their status updates via this [link](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Hosting/18003).

Comment: Thank you for this information, however, I don't believe it's related as I've been seeing this issue for a few days.

Comment: I believe the issue is occurring because of this bug - any help on this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830224/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-firestore-googleapis-due-to-access-contr

Answer (score 0):

I am still not 100% sure as to why this is working however I fixed the issue by:
1. In my `functions/index.js` file, updating the `fullPath` because I believe that the `__dirname + '/../react-ui/build/index.html'` wasn't resolving.

My name `functions/index.js` file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    const fullPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/build/index.html');

    res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
    res.sendFile(fullPath);
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

2. On my build process, I'm moving the build directory into the functions folder to get deployed to Firebase with the functions so my project directory when I'm getting ready to deploy looks like where the build directory in `functions` and `react-ui` is identical:
   [image]

If anyone has more insight into why this is exactly working I would appreciate additional information.

Thanks!

Comment: @EliseChant not 100% confident into why it's working but it is!

Answer (score 0):

Try running `firebase login`. I had this exact issue and it was because my login session had expired.

Alternatively, try `firebase login --no-localhost` if you're having trouble with the standard login.

If you're using ci/cd, use `firebase login:ci --no-localhost`, save your ci token to your environment under `FIREBASE_TOKEN` and deploy with `firebase deploy --only functions --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN`.