# Firestore querying delay

Tags: firebase, networking, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

Check the photo please. Request that goes to firestore.googleapis.com taking so long and it causes delay to other request. Seems like something isn't correct .

How to remove that request? or move it after to the other firestore request?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the Firestore SDK establishing a socket and keeping it open for realtime updates to any queries you make.  All of those queries will reuse that open connection.  The SDK always does this on your first query.  It is not blocking any other requests from your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830224/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-firestore-googleapis-due-to-access-contr

Seems like I got same problem as this person. The error message shows on the console.

Also, when I zoom first few seconds of Network on photo, that error delays to other firestore query for about 1 sec. How can I let those query bypass the error and execute immediately?